In some linux system , echo $DISPLAY shows :1 instead of :0 why is that?
DISPLAY as :1 typically means that your X server instance is running on display :1, but why it doesn't runs in :0, there is no other display nothing else is connected with my laptop, why it chose :1 , my system is rhel 8.4
[work@localhost Desktop]$ xls 
xlsatoms xlsclients xlsfonts 
[work@localhost Desktop]$ xlsclients -display :0 
xlsclients: unable to open display ":0" 
[work@localhost Desktop]$ xlsclients -display :1 
localhost.localdomain gnome-shell 
localhost.localdomain ibus-x11 
localhost.localdomain ibus-extension-gtk3 
localhost.localdomain gsd-power localhost.localdomain gsd-xsettings 
localhost.localdomain gsd-wacom localhost.localdomain gsd-subman 
localhost.localdomain gsd-color localhost.localdomain gsd-clipboard 
localhost. localdomain gsd-keyboard 
localhost.localdomain gsd-media-keys 
localhost.localdomain org,gnome,software localhost.localdomain seapplet 
localhost.localdomain evolution-alarm-notify 
localhost.localdomain gnome-terminal-server


Your display manager might be taking up :0?

@muru it doesn't work like that. The display server spawns the user session for the same X.org $DISPLAY.

@UNREAL does it bother you? Stops you from doing something? Please post the output of ps ax | grep Xorg

@ArtemS.Tashkinov that is not always the case. IIRC LightDM at least had it configurable whether it reused the X server for the user session.
